# Move table position matplotlib python

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, figure

I have created a `figure` that displays a shape and `table` using `matplotlib`. The problem is how its produced. They overlap each other. The shape is to scale so I don't want to alter it. I was wondering how I can alter the overall size of the plot or move the position of the table.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib as mpl

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize = (10,6))
ax.axis('equal')
plt.style.use('ggplot')
ax.grid(False)

xy = 0,0
circle = mpl.patches.Circle(xy, 160, lw = 3, edgecolor = 'black', color = 'b', alpha = 0.1, zorder = 5)
ax.add_patch(circle)   

col_labels=['A','B','C','D','E']
row_labels=['diff','total']

table_vals=[['','','','',''],['','','','','']]

the_table = plt.table(cellText=table_vals,
    colWidths = [0.05]*5,
    rowLabels=row_labels,
    colLabels=col_labels,
    bbox = [0.8, 0.4, 0.2, 0.2])

ax.autoscale()
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Of course you can make the circle smaller, or modify `xlim` and `ylim`, or change the location of your table to a corner... possibilities are endless.

Comment: I've updated the question. The shape it to scale sorry so i can't change that. If I change the location of the table, it goes off the plot

Comment: What about `top center` instead of `top right`? Otherwise use `bbox` as suggested in the answers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Position the table outside the axes

You may use `loc="right"` to position the table right of the axes. Something like `fig.subplots_adjust(right=0.8)` will leave enough space for it.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib as mpl
plt.style.use('ggplot')

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize = (10,6))
fig.subplots_adjust(right=0.8)
ax.axis('equal')

ax.grid(False)

xy = 0,0
circle = mpl.patches.Circle(xy, 160, lw = 3, edgecolor = 'black', 
                            facecolor = 'b', alpha = 0.1, zorder = 5)
ax.add_patch(circle)   

col_labels=['A','B','C','D','E']
row_labels=['diff','total']

table_vals=[['','','','',''],['','','','','']]

the_table = plt.table(cellText=table_vals,
          colWidths = [0.05]*5,
          rowLabels=row_labels,
          colLabels=col_labels,
          loc='right', zorder=3)

ax.autoscale()
plt.show()
```

[image]

#### Put the table in its own axes

You may put the table in a new axes next to the existing one. The advantage is that there is no need to then play with the column width or subplot parameters.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib as mpl
plt.style.use('ggplot')

fig, (ax, ax_table) = plt.subplots(ncols=2, figsize = (10,6),
                                  gridspec_kw=dict(width_ratios=[3,1]))
ax.axis('equal')
ax_table.axis("off")

ax.grid(False)

xy = 0,0
circle = mpl.patches.Circle(xy, 160, lw = 3, edgecolor = 'black', 
                            facecolor = 'b', alpha = 0.1, zorder = 5)
ax.add_patch(circle)   

col_labels=['A','B','C','D','E']
row_labels=['diff','total']

table_vals=[['','','','',''],['','','','','']]

the_table = ax_table.table(cellText=table_vals,
          rowLabels=row_labels,
          colLabels=col_labels,
          loc='center')

ax.autoscale()
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks @ImportanceOfBeingErnest. This is good. Is it possible to have it on the same axis with the plot though. Please see question for more detail

Answer (score 6):

Add the `bbox` argument with your table. (instead of loc)

```
the_table = plt.table(cellText=table_vals,
              colWidths = [0.05]*5,
              rowLabels=row_labels,
              colLabels=col_labels,
              bbox = [0.2, 0.4, 0.4, 0.02])
```

[image: With BBOX]

The `bbox` argument takes 4 inputs: X, Y, Width, Height. Thus X and Y are the coordinates of the bottom left corner. Above, the height was far too small.

**EDIT: Create room to play with**

The idea is to make the `ax` smaller in the same manner.

```
box = ax.get_position()
a.set_position([box.x0, box.y0, box.width * 0.9, box.height])
```

**EDIT 2:** Trying to put the table on the right. As I said, you need to play with the box values, took me about 10 tries to get this. I'm using spyder as an  IDE, so it's really fast.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib as mpl

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize = (10,6))
ax.axis('equal')
plt.style.use('ggplot')
ax.grid(False)

xy = 0,0
circle = mpl.patches.Circle(xy, 160, lw = 3, edgecolor = 'black', color = 'b', alpha = 0.1, zorder = 5)
ax.add_patch(circle)   

col_labels=['A','B','C','D','E']
row_labels=['diff','total']

table_vals=[['','','','',''],['','','','','']]

the_table = plt.table(cellText=table_vals,
          colWidths = [0.05]*5,
          rowLabels=row_labels,
          colLabels=col_labels,
          bbox = [1.1, 0.5, 0.35, 0.1])

box = ax.get_position()
ax.set_position([box.x0, box.y0, box.width * 0.8, box.height])

ax.autoscale()
plt.show()
```

Output:

[image: Table on the right]

Comment: Thanks @Mathieu. Is there anyway to extend the plot size as well. I can squeeze it in but it would be good to have more room to play with.

Comment: @Maxibon Yes, you can modify the position and size of the `axis` on the figure with the code in the EDIT. Let's say you want to place the plot on the left and the table on the right, the space on the side of your circle is useless, thus play with the width and the x position.

Comment: @Maxibon without more knowledge about what you want to do, I can't help more.

Comment: Thanks @Mathieu. Should that be `ax.set_position([box.x0, box.y0, box.width * 0.9, box.height])` instead of `a.set_position`

Comment: @Maxibon Well you need to play with the values, with `box.width * 0.9` you reduce the width by 10%. You might need more, you might need to shift the corner to another position (x0, y0), and so on...

Comment: Can you put it as a full answer. I'll update the question to display how I'm understanding your answer.

Comment: Thanks for this @Mathieu